# Replace Text in Word Document

Tags: c#, string, replace, ms-word, netoffice

I am using the NetOffice library to edit a Word document. In my document, I have a field `"{NAME}"` that I would like to replace with a value `"John Smith"`. However, executing the following code does not work. `Find.Execute` returns false, indicating failure, and no change is reflected in `document.Content.Text`.

```
// Open the template
Application word = new Application();
Document document = word.Documents.Open(fileName, false, true);

// Set up initial behavior in word
word.Visible = false;

// Replace template with final values
foreach (LetterField field in fields)
{
    document.Content.Find.ClearFormatting();
    document.Content.Find.Text = "{" + field.Key + "}";
    document.Content.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    document.Content.Find.Replacement.Text = field.Value;
    document.Content.Find.Execute(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
}
```

I also tried manually replacing `document.Content.Text`, but this removes all formatting from the page, which is also undesirable. How can I replace text in a document in NetOffice?

I notice that setting `document.Content.Find.Text` does not seem to do anything, as checking the value still yields `""`, even after setting it to something else. Is this intended behavior, or am I missing something?

The document contains the following (copied and pasted):

```
Date: {DATE}
{NAME}
{ADDRESSLINE}
{ADDRESSCITY}, {ADDRESSSTATE} {ADDRESSCODE}
```

Some fields are as follows:

```
<"NAME", "John Smith">
<"DATE", "10/28/2021">
```

Comment: By `field "{NAME}"`, do you mean (a) just the text `{NAME}` written in your Word document or (b) an actual "Word field" (those things displayed with a gray background)? I don't think that Find-and-Replace works on the latter, you need to [do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17738336/87698) instead.

Comment: I have the text `"{NAME}"` in the word document.

Comment: can you please share sample of your document...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do word/mail-merge. and that is what it looks like as a binding back to the source document.  Is the merge what you are actually trying to get done?  If so, that is relatively easy to do.  Please confirm.

Comment: @DRapp I am not sure what a word/mail-merge is. I am just trying to replace text in a word document.

Comment: Word Merge is a way of having a template document with {placeholders} where you want to replace during the processing.  A secondary document has nothing but a list of records such as a CSV of those {placeholder} values.  Then with Word Merging, the data from the list is merged with the template document to create a final output document with exactly what you are looking to do find/replace.  Use for bulk work.  Can do with single record, or batch of 1000's as needed.  Is this coming from a Word document?

Comment: @DRapp Okay I think I understand. I am using C# to fill in the fields, though, not a second document or spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with your sample, but, tried with a variation of the Execute method and it works fine for me.

```
        const string TemplateFileName = @"D:\Dev\SO\MyWordDoc.docx";
        const string ResultFileName = @"D:\Dev\SO\MyWordDoc_new.docx";

        var wordApp = new Application();
        var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(TemplateFileName, false, true);
        var status = doc.Content.Find.Execute(findText: "{NAME}", 
                                    matchCase: false,
                                    matchWholeWord: false,
                                    matchWildcards: false,
                                    matchSoundsLike: false,
                                    matchAllWordForms: false,
                                    forward: true, //this may be the one
                                    wrap: false,
                                    format: false,
                                    replaceWith: "My Name Value", 
                                    replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll
                                    );

        doc.SaveAs(ResultFileName);
        doc.Close();
```

I used the syntax from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Find.Execute

for the different parameters.

It may be that you may need to `Execute` with `forward` parameters to be `"True"`, i.e., the 7th parameter.

Result document:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here looks like it could be achieved by using the Mail Merge feature built into word. The feature is designed to take in a list of contact information and replace placeholder text to produce a document addressed to each person in the list.

Microsoft has some good documentation on how to achieve this which I suggest you check out https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705

Comment: But can this be automated through C#? I specifically have an application that I need to be able to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874300/how-do-you-mail-merge-a-word-document-in-c-sharp

Comment: If no other answers are submitted, I will give this the bounty. Technically this doesn't answer my question since I asked specifically about the NetOffice framework, but this provides a good alternative.